# JQuery select parent node and change its class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="abcdef">ABC
<div class="B">bcs</div>
<div id="A" class="C"></div>
<select id="D" style="width:200px;">
    <option value="abc">abc</option>
    <option value="123">123</option>
</select>
</div>
```

I would like to change the class of div class="abcdef", as in my case i will have a lot of div with class starting with "abc.."

But the only id i have here which is consistent is id="A", so i would like to make use of that.

So, my jquery should,

1. Select id="A"
2. Find the parent node where its class starting with "abc"
3. Change the class name

*EDIT
I have not much idea on selecting parent node other than .parentNode, that is the main concern, if i can select the parent ,i think i can sort out the change class name

Comment: and what have you tired so far??

Comment: So write your code. (I don't understand what you're asking here, and you seem to understand the problem enough to come up with a nice algorithm for it.)

Comment: There is any parent node of #A with abcdef class, it's a sibling...

Comment: Use http://api.jquery.com/closest/, with the right selector http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ (you will find it).

Comment: I think that using a class for this is not the best practice, it is not guarandeed that after adding or removing classes to that element 'abcdef' will be at the start.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the `A` element then use .closest() along with attribute start with selector to find the div element with class `abc*` then remove the class and add the new class

```
$('#A').closest('div[class^=abc]').removeClass().addClass('newclass')
$('#A').closest('div[class^=abc]').attr('class', 'newclass')
```

Comment: hi,i am assuming the second code itself will work, am i right to say so? actually my scenario isn't exactly so, where there are numerous div with id="A", and i want all of the div near it with class starting with "abc" to change and not just one, will the code work that way?

Comment: @AnnaBoyle the id attribute has to be unique... so you cannot have more than 1 element with the id `A`, use class attribute to group similar elements

Comment: @AnnaBoyle also do you want to add the same class to all the selected div's or different one

Comment: so i should change id="A" to class ="A"? and the code should be .A instead of #A?

Comment: @AnnaBoyle yes.. like `<div class="A C"></div>` instead of `<div id="A" class="C"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

**If "#A" is the child of ".abc.."

```
 $('#A').parents('div[class^=abc]').removeClass().addClass('NewClass');
```

**if it is .abc.. is previous to #A**

```
 $('#A').prev('div[class^=abc]').removeClass().addClass('NewClass');
```

Answer (score 0):

If in DOM that div is parent of `#A.`

```
$("#A").parent().removeClass().addClass('newclass');
```